# Controlling addLines

Tags: r, charts, quantmod

I have an xts object (NCGSpot) I use for charting and would like to add a vertical line on a given date to the plot. Here is what I do:

```
chartSeries(NCGSpot, TA="addBBands();addLines()", subset="2015-04-02::2016-08-01",theme="white")
```

How can I control where the Lines is drawn. I have seen stuff like

```
addLines(v=anynumber)
```

But I cannot make much sense out of it and could not find any information on it.
Its there any way I pass on a date to addLines and get the line on that date?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `chart_Series`, (better charting capabilities than `chartSeries`) you can create vertical lines from scratch using an xts object containing a matrix type of logical, where TRUE applies to the dates where vertical lines are desired.  The argument `on` should be set to 1 or -1 if you want the vertical lines on your main chart. Setting -1 will put the lines behind the candles. Other useful parameters included col and border (should be self explanatory).  Here is an example to get you started:

```
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("AAPL")

xt <- xts(rep(FALSE, NROW(AAPL)), index(AAPL))
dates_for_vertical_marks <- c("2016-02-01", "2016-04-29")
xt[dates_for_vertical_marks, ] <- TRUE

xt2 <- xts(rep(FALSE, NROW(AAPL)), index(AAPL))
dates_for_vertical_marks <- c("2016-07-01")
xt2[dates_for_vertical_marks, ] <- TRUE


chart_Series(AAPL, subset="2016")
add_TA(xt, on =-1, col= "orange", border='blue')
add_TA(xt2, on = 1, col= "darkgreen", border='darkgreen')
```

[image: vert lines]